# How to get the next sibling match in a list with different elements using JQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, siblings

For some reason I'm having a problem with getting the next match in a list with `<li>` and `<div>`.  I just need to match the next `.infobox` that matches after `<li>` that was clicked.

```html
<ul>
  <li />
  <li />
  <li />
  <div class="infobox" />
  <li />
  <li />
  <li />
  <div class="infobox" />
  ...repeats this pattern a few more times
```

Attempt 1

```js
$('ul li').on('click', function() {
  $(this).nextAll('.infobox').first();
});
```

With this one, clicking on the third `<li />` does not select the `.infobox`

```html
// e.g.
<li />
<li />
<li />
<div class="infobox" />
// clicking on the first <li /> selects the last <li /> and .infobox
// clicking on the second <li /> selects the .infobox correctly
// clicking on the third <li /> does not select .infobox at all
```

Attempt 2

```js
$('ul li').on('click', function() {
  $(this).next('.infobox');
});
```

With this one, clicking on only the third `<li>` selects `.infobox`

```html
// e.g.
<li />
<li />
<li />
<div class="infobox" />
// clicking on the first <li /> does not select .infobox
// clicking on the second <li /> does not select .infobox
// clicking on the third <li /> selects .infobox
```

Attempt 3

```js
$('ul li').on('click', function() {
  $(this).nextUntil('.infobox').next().last();
});
```

With this one, clicking on the third `<li>` does not select `.infobox`

```html
// e.g.
<li />
<li />
<li />
<div class="infobox" />
// clicking on the first <li /> selects .infobox
// clicking on the second <li /> selects .infobox
// clicking on the third <li /> does not select .infobox
```

Comment: `<div>` is invalid child of `<ul>`. Browser layouts are not predictable when markup is invalid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update:

It is actually possible to this even faster with `jQuery`,
using `pseudo` class in the selector: `.nextAll('.infobox:first')`.

```js
$('li').on('click', function() {
  $(this).nextAll('.infobox:first').addClass('red');
});
```

```css
.red {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>not infobox</li>
  <li>not infobox</li>
  <li class="infobox">infobox</li>
  <li>not infobox</li>
  <li>not infobox</li>
  <li>not infobox</li>
  <li class="infobox">infobox</li>
</ul>
```

---

You would need to loop over the items that remain in that array of `li`.

Once a class has been found you would need to `break` out of the loop, otherwise all next siblings with that class will be selected.

```js
$('li').each(function(i) {
  $(this).on('click', function() {
    for(let j = i; j < $('li').length; j++){
      if($('li').eq(j).hasClass('infobox')){
        $('li').eq(j).addClass('red');
        break;
      }
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.red {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>not infobox</li>
  <li>not infobox</li>
  <li class="infobox">infobox</li>
  <li>not infobox</li>
  <li>not infobox</li>
  <li>not infobox</li>
  <li class="infobox">infobox</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Does .infobox need to be `<li>`? Do you have a solution when it is a <div>?

Comment: @JosephK. No, it doesn't, but it has to be in your ```html```, since ```ul``` can only have ```li``` as child.

Comment: @JosephK., the ```.nextAll()``` solution above allows it to combine with ```div```, but it is not good practise to have them as child elements of either a ```ul``` or ```ol```.

Comment: ah, yeah I understand, I just tried and it worked, thank you!